# Error: Unable to read database "/var/lib/vnstat/eth0": No such file or directory

Tags: networking, vnstat

I am using `vnstat` for first time and I am getting this error while using `vnstat -d`

> Error: Unable to read database "/var/lib/vnstat/eth0": No such file or directory

The file in `/var/lib/vnstat` are

```
 enp1s0  wlp2s0
```

These are my network interfaces.

I can understand it using `eth0` file but how can I changed default file to `enp1s0` from `eth0`.

When I use `sudo vnstat -u -i eth0`, I get error

> Error: Unable to read database "/var/lib/vnstat/eth0": No such file or directory
>   Error: Unable to get interface "eth0" statistics.
>   Only available interfaces can be added for monitoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default interface is defined in the `/etc/vnstat.conf` file:

```
$ head /etc/vnstat.conf 
# vnStat 1.13 config file
##

# default interface
Interface "eth0"

# location of the database directory
DatabaseDir "/var/lib/vnstat"

# locale (LC_ALL) ("-" = use system locale)
```

Although you could change it there, a possibly better way is to create your own `~/.vnstatrc` file and modify that:

```
cp /etc/vnstat.conf ~/.vnstatrc
```

then use an editor of your choice to change `Interface "eth0"` to `Interface "enp1s0"` in the local copy.

See `man vnstat.conf` for full details.

Comment: What about wireless interface

Comment: @Debian_yadav what about it, exactly? AFAIK `vnstat` can only have a single default interface, it doesn't differentiate by type. You will need to choose whether you want that to be the wired or wireless one.

Comment: @steeldriver vnStat has no built-in limit for the number of interfaces it supports. The `Interface` configuration option only defines the interface that gets shown if no other interface is specified with the `-i` parameter. If no parameters are given for the `vnstat` command then a summary of all tracked interfaces will be shown by default.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by changing `interface` in the file `/etc/vnstat.conf` from `eth0` to `wlp3s0`. If you don't know your network interfaces, you could get by the command `ip addr`.

Answer (score 1):

Please start first vnstat service.
No matter if configuration (/etc/vnstat.conf or ~/.vnstatrc) is edited or NOT.

```
systemctl start vnstat
/etc/rc.d/init.d/vnstat start
```

Answer (score 0):

Many parson answers correctly but missing one more thing

Needs to change configuration in two places **`/etc/vnstat.conf`** and **`HOME Directory/.vnstatrc`** (Ex. `/home/sagar/.vnstatrc`)

Change default interface from eth0 to whatever in your machine like `enp1s0` or `wlp2s0` or `wlp3s0`

In both files statment will be like`Interface "wlp3s0"`

Save file and check again useing coommend `vnstat -d`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  It's best if you post a complete answer, since we aren't sure which other answer(s) you are referencing.  For more info about our Q&A format, check out our [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour)